# How to split a string (such as "xPM - yPM") into two strings, Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, date, swift, time

If I have a string such as `xAM - yPM` is it possible to split the string into 2 strings using the `-` as the point where the string is split?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818197/how-to-split-a-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `componentsSeparatedByString` function:

```
var splittedArray = yourString.componentsSeparatedByString(" - ")
println(splittedArray[0]) // "xPM"
println(splittedArray[1]) // "yPM"
```

Comment: The answer is incorrect, there is a compile error,. Only a character is allowed as a split character, not a String. There is also a typo: there must be a space prior to the `=` in the first line. Array index `0` is used twice. The result and trading and leading space characters respectively.

Comment: Why a not use componentsSeparatedByString, it has two added benefits: 1. The separator is not limited to a single character. 2. There is no extra '$0' in a closure.

Comment: @Zaph Thanks for the correction. Don't know why I didn't use it in first place.

Comment: I've got no access to a IDE at the moment. But that's no excuse. Fixed it.