# How to slice a string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to slice a string in Swift, for example

```
var str = "Tower Capital, 99822, Building 2399"
```

My goal is to slice only `Tower Capital`, technically what I want is to slice up to the `,` but not included the comma.

So my goal is to get only `"Tower Capital"`

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818197/how-to-split-a-string-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string and get the first part like this:

```
var str = "Tower Capital, 99822, Building 2399"
let firstItem = str.componentsSeparatedByString(",").first
```

Or when using Swift >= 3:

```
str.components(separatedBy: ",").first
```

Comment: That's an archaic usage. Use `str.components(separatedBy: ",").first` now...

Comment: There might be some people still using Xcode 7... updated my answer :)

Comment: @AndréSlotta They really shouldn't be, and we shouldn't be encouraging it :p Swift 3 is already on it's way out lol

Comment: @Alexander true :)

Comment: Thanks @AndréSlotta